# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I have installed BIRT modules in Eclipse but while generating Preview I am getting below error.
I am not sure where should i place js.jar file on the file system.
Please advise.

```
    AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
    at  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.&lt;init&gt;(PreparedQuery.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.&lt;init&gt;(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.&lt;init&gt;(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQueryUtil.newInstance(PreparedQueryUtil.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl.prepare(DataEngineImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.doPrepareQuery(AbstractDataEngine.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doPrepareQuery(DteDataEngine.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.prepare(AbstractDataEngine.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportExecutor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:179)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptOrFnNode cannot be found by org.eclipse.birt.data_4.4.2.v201501161327
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due [to a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351482). Updating will solve the issue.